# I want to use the result of a function in another function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
some_list = [ [ ], [ ], [ ] ]

def my_func(sum):
     ...
     a = 0
     b = 1
     return a, b
```

I'm trying to append to the given index in `some_list` by getting the index from `a` and `b`.

What do I need to write so that this code below would work?

```
some_list[a].append(win)
some_list[b].append(loss)
```

Comment: not exactly clear what you want to achieve try including a example.

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly are you struggling with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign two variables at once to the call of your function, like this:

```
some_list = [ [ ], [ ], [ ] ]

def my_func(sum):
     ...
     a = 0
     b = 1
     return a, b

a, b = my_func(sum) # this here

some_list[a].append(win)
some_list[b].append(loss)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by 'work' you mean that you want to use the return value of the function as the index of an array.

```
a, b = my_func(whatever)
some_list[a].append(win)
some_list[b].append(loss)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
some_list = [ [ ], [ ], [ ] ]

def my_func(sum):
     a = 0
     b = 1
     return a, b



sum = 5
a,b = my_func(sum)

win = 'aaa'
loss = 'bbb'
some_list[a].append(win)
some_list[b].append(loss)

print(some_list)
```